# What makes a melody the “main melody” of a song?

Tags: composition, melody, texture

A melody cannot exist with just one note, it requires 2 which implies that more change could be the biggest factor in making a melody the center of a composition. I am essentially making the assumption that providing a melody with more movement (rhythmic variation) would be the core element in causing it to stand out (be the “main melody”).

Although, I also understand that to an extent, it is a matter of perspective on what the “main melody” of a song is. I’m wondering if there are any other factors that i’m missing in making a melody the center (main melody) of a composition AND if my assumption above about rhythmic variation being the main tool for creating a distinct melody would be correct.

Not that the it 100% exists per se, I am slightly of the belief that a listener can decide what melody he/she cares the most about within a composition. But, what are the various ways a “main melody” differentiates itself from the other voices?

Comment: Some clarification, please. Are you asking for a definition of “melody” (i.e. “necessary and sufficient conditions”), how to differentiate the “main” melody from other melodies in a song, or something else?

Comment: You don't even need two different notes: e.g. "One Note Samba"

Comment: @PiedPiper In "One Note Samba"'s defense, there are eventually some other notes.

Comment: Correct. I’m wondering how to differentiate the “main melody”, not that it actually exists per se (because I am of the belief that it’s down to perspective). I’m asking what factors contribute to one voice standing out more than another. And I was also making the assumption that melodies with more movement stand out more so I was wondering if that is an accurate assumption.

Comment: A part will tend to stand out if it is louder, or higher in pitch. More movement does not necessarily make a part stand out - consider the Passacaglia from Bach's Passacaglia and Fugue. Also - do you consider the 4-note theme of Beethoven's 5th symphony to be a melody in the sense you are talking about?

Comment: The first 2 measures of "Mars" from *The Planets* better be a melody despite being the same note repeated a lot, right?

Comment: Speaking of "Mars" from *The Planets*, its first 2 measures have the harp part playing notes in alternating octaves, making it the part with the most movement. Yet that part can barely be heard at all in the orchestral mix, with the repeated-note melody being far more prominent. Clearly, movement isn't everything.

Comment: Melody is not just a number of notes (from one and more), but their **duration**. And, to an extent, their dynamics.

Comment: And - ask any jazzer, they'll tell you it's the original melody, but - any amount of other melodies will fit the chord sequence. Where does that leave us?

Comment: I think the concept of melody is like the concept of music itself. 98% of people would agree on what music is and what melodies are, but it’s also difficult to define either term. If we can’t pin down what a melody is, it’s even harder to clarify what a “main” melody is.

Comment: Note, the comments section here isn't a permanent or official part of the question. I'm going to take the liberty of adding your clarification to the question itself; you can also make more edits if you'd like. (Also, side note: It's not always a given that there even *is* "a melody"! There are lots of kinds of music where it's not a priority.)

Comment: See the notion of [Hauptstimme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hauptstimme), by the way. So looks like you're narrowing your interest to contexts in which there *are* multiple simultaneous "melodic" [linear] voices. Note, the answer might not just be in the notes chosen, but instrumentation. Schoenberg says there "human voice is always Haupstimme when present." Making a melody more prominent can be as simple as giving it a louder dynamic marking, or giving it to an instrument with a bold or incisive tone.

Comment: @AndyBonner That the human voice is always the main melody when present is an interesting assertion coming from Schoenberg. I’m surprised almost nobody agreed that rhythmic variation is what most makes a voice stand out (which still seems to be the case from what i’ve heard in music in my life). But nonetheless, there’s a lot of good answers so thank you. I’d never heard of Haupstimme until now.

Answer (score 3):

There's a popular phrase ["I know art when I see it"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_know_it_when_I_see_it).  There should be a similar "I know a melody when I hear it".

If you were to separate out all the instruments or singers into their own tracks, and listen to each separately, it should be obvious which is the main melody - it's the one that still sounds like a tune. *But it's possible that the melody changes between instruments as the song progresses.*

An accompaniment can span a much larger range than the melody.  It can have a more complex rhythm than the melody. But if you play it on its own, it still sounds like an accompaniment to something.

The human brain is good at "locking on" to tunes, in the same way that it's possible to listen to one conversation in a crowded room.  So the melody sounds dominant, even if it is no louder than the accompaniment.

Comment: Polyphony complicates things a lot. I swear my ability to listen to a certain Well-Tempered Klavier Fugue in F Minor is ruined because the first recording of it I listened to ruthlessly emphasized its topmost line instead of its subject above all else.

Answer (score 3):

We should probably start by saying music does not always use melody. Some percussion music, ambient music, etc. could be considered with work with other musical aspects but not melody.

Also, not all music has a "main" melody where other melodic material can some how be labelled as subordinate to the main melody. Some duets and contrapuntal music will use multiple melodies that are *equal* in terms of importance.

Having made those caveats, I would say the thing that distinguishes melody to be either unique to stand as a proper melody or as a "main" melody above subordinate material is the extent that melody can be distinguished as unique from other existing melodic material.

What I'm driving at is the difference between common figuration patterns like Alberti basses or segments of scale runs compared to a proper melody. Consider an Alberti bass accompaniment, for example, this accompaniment from a Mozart piano sonata...

[image]

Such a pattern can be found all over in classical music. It isn't unique. It's the same broken chord pattern of lower tone, upper, middle, upper applied to chord progression `I I V4/2 I`. Notice also that the top pitch throughout is all `G`. It provides some degree of melodic material, because the chord is broken into a line of single pitches. But compare its un-unique pattern to bona fide melody based on broken chord material, for example, this from Bach...

[image]

...which has a much more unique identity. Notice that as the line unfolds with broken chord material the top of each beat forms a continuous ascent `C D E`. Also, examine the note top note ascending/descending direction of each move. In terms of both the overall contour of the line and its note to note details it isn't like a simple Alberti bass pattern.

When you consider just the direction changes of a melody that aspect is called *melodic contour*. You can examine melodic contour at various levels. Direction only, interval of change, or even pitch letter. Although interval or pitch letter only, without octave reference, would leave the exact direction of movement unclear.

Nevertheless, even pitch letters alone are enough of a unique melodic identifier that Haydn's complete works were indexed by Bryant and Chapman in *A Melodic Index to Haydn's Instrumental Music*. An example of the melodic incipits by letters only looks like this...

[image]

Another well known example of unique melody working only with pitch change and melodic contour is Fux's *species counterpoint* lessons where the *cantus firmi* are all given in whole notes, like this...

[image]

The point is that *melodic contour* alone is enough to create unique melodies. What amount of pitch variety is enough to create a unique melody, a melody that is not likely to be confused with another? Bryant and Chapman's index of Haydn's melodies would seem to provide a good standard. But I don't know if they or some other scholar tried to quantify a degree of uniqueness in the index.

You can also achieve melodic uniqueness from plain common patterns using rhythm. Notice in comparing the Mozart and Bach examples that along with a difference in contour the rhythm of the Mozart accompaniment is all eighth notes, while the Bach melody used sixteenths, eighths, and rests.

You can take a plain scale...

[image]

...and add only rhythm to create a unique melody...

[image]

Getting back to your original question of what makes a "main" melody, I think, at least in part, you can determine that by find the melodic line that is most unique ,among the various parts, in terms of melodic contour and rhythm. In this example from a Mozart string quartet...

[image]

...notice how the top line, the first violin, is much more unique in terms of melodic contour and rhythm that the other parts. That makes the first violin, at least in that particular passage, the "main" melody, and the other parts are accompaniment.

Not all music will work this way. There is not always a clear main melody.

In a duet, like this one by Mozart, the parts a even in terms of melodic uniqueness and interest.

[image]

Another example could be a hymn like this...

[image]

...where the four SATB parts are meant to be roughly equal, in terms of relative ease to sing and interesting line for each part of a chorus, and the rhythm in all half notes underscores the part equality.

Also, understand that the idea of a "main" melody does not have to be fixed to one part. In a fugue the *subject* and its *answer* would be the "main" melodic ideas. As a fugue unfolds the subject and answer get stated in the various voices. So the main melodic ideas jump around between parts in that kind of composition.

There are other more obvious ways to know what is the "main" melody.

In a pop song it's typical that the person singing the lyrics has the main melody.

Playing the main melody louder is another way to "bring out" the main melody. For example, this Chopin prelude...

[image]

...where the main melody is in the treble clef but has relatively little movement compared to the bass clef accompaniment. Later in the short piece the treble clef develops an interesting contour making clear it is the main melody.

> A melody cannot exist with just one note, it requires 2

To the extent pitch contour strongly impacts melodic uniqueness that is true, but there will be examples to find that challenge that contention. Surely, rhythm and dynamics would be ways to make a one *pitch* take on a level of interest and uniqueness to become a main melody. (I assume you meant 2 different *pitches* rather than literal *notes*. Two notes, like two quarter notes, and then you're done, will not make a decent melody!)

> if my assumption above about rhythmic variation being the main tool for creating a distinct melody would be correct.

I think this is correct. Rhythm is a very important factor in developing good melody.